Python Libraries for Sentence Classification Based on Keyword
I want to separate a list of sentences into two lists based on whether they match the sentiment of a specific keyword. For example:
valid_keyword = "Guest Accepted"

sentences = [
    "Guest Allowed", "Max Guest Allowed 1", "Guest Not Allowed", 
    "No Guest Allowed", "Guest Restricted", "Max Guest Allowed 0", 
    "Guest Allowed on Request"
]

I want to separate the list in the following way:
valid_sentences, which contains sentences that match the sentiment of the valid_keyword ("Guest Accepted").
invalid_sentences, which contains sentences that do not match the sentiment of the valid_keyword.
The expected output would be:
valid_sentences = ["Guest Allowed", "Max Guest Allowed 1", "Guest Allowed on Request"]
invalid_sentences = ["Guest Not Allowed", "No Guest Allowed", "Guest Restricted", "Max Guest Allowed 0"]

I already tried VaderSentiment, but didn't get what I expected.
What are the suitable Python libraries that I should go for this process that will give maximum accuracy?

maybe you should ask on similar portal for DataScience or CrossValidated

There is a tidy yet effective solution using Zero-Shot Classification pipeline presented by HuggingFace which may do what you desire. After installing the library you can use it like follows:
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline(model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
pipe([
    "Guest Allowed", "Max Guest Allowed 1", "Guest Not Allowed", 
    "No Guest Allowed", "Guest Restricted", "Max Guest Allowed 0", 
    "Guest Allowed on Request"],
    candidate_labels=["Guest Accepted", "Guest Not Accepted"],
)
# # output
# [{'sequence': 'Guest Allowed',
#   'labels': ['Guest Accepted', 'Guest Not Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9912997484207153, 0.008700196631252766]},
#  {'sequence': 'Max Guest Allowed 1',
#   'labels': ['Guest Accepted', 'Guest Not Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9896429777145386, 0.010356982238590717]},
#  {'sequence': 'Guest Not Allowed',
#   'labels': ['Guest Not Accepted', 'Guest Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9956033229827881, 0.004396690987050533]},
#  {'sequence': 'No Guest Allowed',
#   'labels': ['Guest Not Accepted', 'Guest Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9929953217506409, 0.007004666142165661]},
#  {'sequence': 'Guest Restricted',
#   'labels': ['Guest Not Accepted', 'Guest Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9871166348457336, 0.012883339077234268]},
#  {'sequence': 'Max Guest Allowed 0',
#   'labels': ['Guest Not Accepted', 'Guest Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.5833010673522949, 0.41669896245002747]},
#  {'sequence': 'Guest Allowed on Request',
#   'labels': ['Guest Accepted', 'Guest Not Accepted'],
#   'scores': [0.9872869849205017, 0.012713048607110977]}]

Feel free to change the model or candidate labels to adapt the solution for your specific use case.

I notice the sentences are all short. Is it possible to simply make a list of all the possible candidate strings, and use exact (but case-insensitive) matching?
And, as a backup, when you get a string not in your list, pass it to the mnli model in meti's answer.  (And log it, so you can add it to the your lookup table in the future.)
This would allow you to reliably treat "Max Guest Allowed 0" as not accepted, which I see was the only one the MNLI model struggled on. It would also be much quicker, in CPU terms.
